# batch: get last folder name from path from txt

Tags: batch-file

i need take paths from txt and get last folder name and then use it.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set InputFile=somar.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (
set path=%%x
:shift
for /f "tokens=1* delims=\/" %%i in ( "!path!" ) do (
    set folder=%%i
    set path=%%j
    )
if not [!path!] == [] goto :shift

echo folder: !folder!
)
endlocal
```

problem is that it works only for first line in txt. where is the problem?

Comment: Do your paths include a file name at the end? Or are they just path information without a file? My interpretation is the latter (no file name), but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems:

1) Your FOR loop is broken the moment you issue a GOTO. You will not get any more FOR loop iterations after GOTO. You could fix this by moving your GOTO loop into a subroutine and then CALL the subroutine from within your DO loop.

2) The PATH environment variable has a reserved meaning for Windows. You should never use that variable name for your own purposes, even if it is localized as you have it. It isn't worth tempting fate. Simply use a different variable name.

3) Perhaps not an issue with your data, but `!` is a valid character for a file or folder name. Your expansion of FOR variables will corrupt names containing `!` if delayed expansion is enabled. This can be fixed by toggling delayed expansion on and off as needed.

You also have a minor inefficiency - There is no need to use TYPE with your FOR loop. You can simply let FOR read the file directly. (unless the file is unicode)

You could take all the recommendations above, but there is a *much* simpler solution :-)

*EDIT - change made to handle a path that ends with `\`*

```
@echo off
set "InputFile=somar.txt"
for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%A in ("%inputFile%") do (
  for %%F in ("%%A\.") do echo folder: %%~nxF
)
```

The `~nx` FOR variable modifiers directly give you the name and extension of the end of the path. Type `HELP FOR` from the command line to read about all the modifiers that are available to FOR variables.

Comment: I think the OP is after the last folder name rather than the filename, if the text file only has path names.

Comment: @BaliC - Yes, the OP has indicated the data contains paths ending with a folder name, not a file name. The modifiers don't care if the ending node is a file or folder *except* my original solution wouldn't work if the path happens to end with \. Your comment made me realize I needed to make a change. The code is now more robust.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that about the modifiers, +1

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out why someone would down vote this answer. A comment from the down voter sure would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> For variable filenames:

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

set "File=File.ext"
Call :Get_paths "%InputFile%"

Pause&exit

:Get_paths
Set "AbsolutePath=%~dp1"
set "AbsolutePath=%AbsolutePath:\= %"
FOR %%# in (%AbsolutePath%) do (
    Set "LastFolder=%%#"
    Echo Folder: %%#
)
Echo Last Folder: %LastFolder%
GOTO:EOF
```

**Output**:

```
Folder: C:
Folder: Users
Folder: Administrador
Folder: Desktop

Last Folder: Desktop
```

> For files:

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

set "File=test.txt"

For /F "Tokens=* usebackq" %%# in ("%FILE%") DO (   
    Set "AbsolutePath=%%~dp#"
    Call set "AbsolutePath=%%AbsolutePath:\= %%"
    CMD /Q /C "@FOR %%@ in (%%AbsolutePath%%) do (Echo Folder: %%@)"
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: This will not work as written if the last folder name includes space, semicolon, or comma. Also, it assumes the paths in the file contain a file name at the end, and the parent folder for each file is wanted. The question is a bit vague as to whether the path includes a file, but the OP states the OP code works on the 1st line, and it simply takes the last node, not the parent of the last node. So this answer does not match my interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

InputFile content must contains filename or folder. 
ex)

```
D:\Test1  <= folder
D:\Test2\file.txt  <= file

D:\Test3\01. folder <= folder but recognize file. that contain extension.
```

My code is:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET lastFolder=
SET InputFile=somar.txt

FOR /F %%F IN (%InputFile%) DO (
    CALL :__GetFolderName "%%F"
    @ECHO lastFolder: !lastFolder!
)

GOTO :EOF


:: ******************** Inner  Batch
:__GetFolderName
IF "%~x1"=="" SET lastFolder=%~n1 & GOTO :EOF

SET dp=%~dp1

CALL :__GetFolderName "%dp:~0,-1%"

GOTO :EOF
:: ********************

ENDLOCAL
```

Result is:

```
lastFolder: Test1
lastFolder: Test2
lastFolder: Test3
```